# combining date function into one

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on date extracting for voice based application. I want to know how can i check date and also add flag like user asked for higher date then today in one function. Right now I am using similar function to do so but it would be great if someone can guide me to make it one. My code is following,

checkedDateFlag, checkedDate how can I make this function in one so that i can get right date and also get flag (true)

## Code

```
            let  ent  = [{
            entity:  'sys-number',
            location: [23, 25],
            value:  '12',
            confidence:  1,
            metadata: {
                numeric_value:  1
                }
            },
            {
                entity:  'sys-date',
                location: [23, 40],
                value:  '2017-02-16',
                confidence:  1,
                metadata: {
                calendar_type:  'GREGORIAN',
                timezone:  'GMT'
            }
            },
            {
                entity:  'sys-number',
                location: [36, 40],
                value:  '2018', 
                confidence:  1,
                metadata: {
                    numeric_value:  2018
                }
            },
            {
                entity:  'sys-date',
                location: [49, 52],
                value:  '2030-12-17',
                confidence:  1,
                metadata: {
                    calendar_type:  'GREGORIAN',
                    timezone:  'GMT'
                }
            }
            ];

            const  dateChecker  = (filteredDates, currentDate) => {
            // This function checking date higher than todays date and replace higher date with current date. 
            return  filteredDates.map(f  => {
                let  fd  =  new  Date(f);
                if(fd  >  currentDate) {
                    return  currentDate;
                } else {
                    return  fd;
                }
            })
            }

            const  dateCheckerFlag  = (filteredDates, currentDate) => {
                // This function return true if date is higher and I can check it later and create response saying you have provided higher date than today. I can only issue statement till today and then issue the statement 
                for (let  f  of  filteredDates) {
                    let  fd  =  new  Date(f);
                    if(fd  >  currentDate) {
                        return  true
                    } else {
                        return  false;
                    }
            }


            let  filteredDates  =  ent.filter(f  => {
                if (f.entity  ===  'sys-date') {
                    return  f.value
                }
            }).map(f  =>  f.value);

            let  checkedDateFlag  = helper.dateCheckerFlag(filteredDates, currentDate);
            let  checkedDate  =  helper.dateChecker(filteredDates, currentDate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend against combining these two functions. Although they seem to do the same thing they have completely different output signatures (boolean vs array).

If you think they have lot of repeated code. Maybe the following can be an approach. I will leave combined and separate functions. But strongly recommend the seperate one.

```
 var  ent  = [{
        entity:  'sys-number',
        location: [23, 25],
        value:  '12',
        confidence:  1,
        metadata: {
            numeric_value:  1
            }
        },
        {
            entity:  'sys-date',
            location: [23, 40],
            value:  '2017-02-16',
            confidence:  1,
            metadata: {
            calendar_type:  'GREGORIAN',
            timezone:  'GMT'
        }
        },
        {
            entity:  'sys-number',
            location: [36, 40],
            value:  '2018', 
            confidence:  1,
            metadata: {
                numeric_value:  2018
            }
        },
        {
            entity:  'sys-date',
            location: [49, 52],
            value:  '2030-12-17',
            confidence:  1,
            metadata: {
                calendar_type:  'GREGORIAN',
                timezone:  'GMT'
            }
        }
        ];
        // we convert to date format here itself less
        var  filteredDates  =  ent.filter(f  => (f.entity  ===  'sys-date')).map(f  =>  new Date(f.value));  

        var getCurrentDate = ()=>new Date();

        var checkIfOlder =  (f/*:dateformat*/) =>(f > getCurrentDate());

        var replaceFutureDates = function(f/*:dateformat*/) {
                return (checkIfOlder(f)) ? getCurrentDate() : f;
        }

        /* cleaner IMHO*/
        var checkedDateFlag = filteredDates.every(checkIfOlder);
        var checkedDate = filteredDates.map(replaceFutureDates);

        /* combined function but very confusing output signature

        var dateMapper = (dates, onlyCheck)=> {
              if(onlyCheck) {
                  return dates.every(checkIfOlder);
              }
              return dates.map(replaceFutureDates);
        }

        var checkedDateFlag = dateMapper(filteredDates)
        var checkedDate =dateMapper(filteredDates, true)

        */
```